# Is it possible to set the Flat File Source Component in Biztalk to read "Ragged Right" Files?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, flat-file

There is the need to import a "Ragged Right" flate File with Biztalk into some Destination places like a SQL Database and to a CRM Webservice.

The File is from the following format

```
Column1(10characters)Column2(13characters)Column3(17Chars.)Column4(till Row deliminator CRLF)
```

Where can I set this in the Biztalk in the Flat File Schema Wizard that the last column has no fixed width?

I know it will work in SSIS but this is no option. We now need to do this with Biztalk2010

Comment: Is there a maximum possible width of that last column?

Comment: Can you post a real sample (with 2 rows at minimum) please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a better answer

From the blog [Early Termination with Position Flat Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/skaufman/2004/05/07/early-termination-with-position-flat-files/)

> To make BizTalk recognize an early terminator you need to open your schema in a text editor and add allow_early_termination = “true” to the xs:annotation node.  This property is not exposed in the BizTalk XSD editor.

This article was probably about BizTalk 2004, but it still works in BizTalk 2013 R2.  So just right click your schema, select Open With and select the XML (Text) Editor and make the change as above.

**Update:** Just checked in Visual Studio 2013 and those properties are now available in the Schema Properties

[image]

Comment: thank you Dijkgraaf for your answers. We tried both and they are both working but this one is easier to apply.

Comment: Yes, and no side effects, unlike my first answer.   I did think this feature existed but could not see it in the XSD editor, but when I searched with the correct key words (BizTalk flat file allow early termination) this blog came up to remind me of where to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle it.

Given a sample file like

```
Column1   Column2      Column3          Column4             {CR}{LF}
123456789012345678901231234567890123456712345678901234567890{CR}{LF}
Test1A    Test1B       Test1C           Test1D{CR}{LF}
Test2A    Test2B       Test2C           Testing2D{CR}{LF}
```

Set the last column to Positional Length of 1 and Max Occurs of unbounded afterwards by editing the schema.

Your XML output will look like the below.  You can then re-assemble the last column with a map using the Cumulative Functiod with the scope parameter set to 1.
**Note**: It does not however preserve white space, which could be an issue that would need to be addressed.

**XML Output**

```
<Ragged xmlns="http://Scratch.Ragged">
    <Ragged_Child1 xmlns="">
        <Column1>Column1</Column1>
        <Column2>Column2</Column2>
        <Column3>Column3</Column3>
        <Column4>C</Column4>
        <Column4>o</Column4>
        <Column4>l</Column4>
        <Column4>u</Column4>
        <Column4>m</Column4>
        <Column4>n</Column4>
        <Column4>4</Column4>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
        <Column4/>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1 xmlns="">
        <Column1>1234567890</Column1>
        <Column2>1234567890123</Column2>
        <Column3>12345678901234567</Column3>
        <Column4>1</Column4>
        <Column4>2</Column4>
        <Column4>3</Column4>
        <Column4>4</Column4>
        <Column4>5</Column4>
        <Column4>6</Column4>
        <Column4>7</Column4>
        <Column4>8</Column4>
        <Column4>9</Column4>
        <Column4>0</Column4>
        <Column4>1</Column4>
        <Column4>2</Column4>
        <Column4>3</Column4>
        <Column4>4</Column4>
        <Column4>5</Column4>
        <Column4>6</Column4>
        <Column4>7</Column4>
        <Column4>8</Column4>
        <Column4>9</Column4>
        <Column4>0</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1 xmlns="">
        <Column1>Test1A</Column1>
        <Column2>Test1B</Column2>
        <Column3>Test1C</Column3>
        <Column4>T</Column4>
        <Column4>e</Column4>
        <Column4>s</Column4>
        <Column4>t</Column4>
        <Column4>1</Column4>
        <Column4>D</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1 xmlns="">
        <Column1>Test2A</Column1>
        <Column2>Test2B</Column2>
        <Column3>Test2C</Column3>
        <Column4>T</Column4>
        <Column4>e</Column4>
        <Column4>s</Column4>
        <Column4>t</Column4>
        <Column4>i</Column4>
        <Column4>n</Column4>
        <Column4>g</Column4>
        <Column4>2</Column4>
        <Column4>D</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
</Ragged>
```

**Map**

[image: Map]

**Map Output**

```
<ns0:Ragged xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.Ragged">
    <Ragged_Child1>
        <Column1>Column1</Column1>
        <Column2>Column2</Column2>
        <Column3>Column3</Column3>
        <Column4>Column4</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1>
        <Column1>1234567890</Column1>
        <Column2>1234567890123</Column2>
        <Column3>12345678901234567</Column3>
        <Column4>12345678901234567890</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1>
        <Column1>Test1A</Column1>
        <Column2>Test1B</Column2>
        <Column3>Test1C</Column3>
        <Column4>Test1D</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
    <Ragged_Child1>
        <Column1>Test2A</Column1>
        <Column2>Test2B</Column2>
        <Column3>Test2C</Column3>
        <Column4>Testing2D</Column4>
    </Ragged_Child1>
</ns0:Ragged>
```